# Give an example of a UFD having a subring which is not a UFD.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Give an example of a UFD having a subring which is not a UFD.

I thought of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$.
Could you please explain my question. I am trying grasp the concepts, need help.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}] \subset \mathbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/3}]$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't know if $\mathbb Z[e^{2\pi i / 3}]$ is a UFD ?

Comment: @Complexanalysis It's a Euclidean ring.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Take any integral domain which is not a UFD and consider it as a subring of its field of fractions. (Fields are UFD for trivial reasons and if you don't accept this, take the polynomial ring over it)

Comment: how can you be so fast... :D ...Simple. elegant..

Answer (score 14):

Consider $\mathbb C$ , it is a field hence obviously $UFD $ but if you consider a subring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-5}]$, it is not a UFD . In fact,
$9=3.3$ and also $9= (2+\sqrt{-5} ) . (2-\sqrt{-5})$ , Hence the factorization is not unique.

Answer (score 8):

One question to ask after reviewing the two answers already posted is whether the existence of an extension $S\subset R$, with $R$ a UFD and the nonunits of $S$ being nonunits in $R$, makes $S$ a UFD.

While plausible, this is also false. For instance $k[x^2,x^3]\subset k[x]$ is a counterexample for any UFD $k$. This is because $x^2$ and $x^3$ are irreducible and yet $x^6=(x^2)^3=(x^3)^2$.

Answer (score 6):

$\mathbb{Z}[2i]$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. First one is [not integrally closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain), so can't be UFD, second [is Euclidean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#As_a_Euclidean_domain).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am beating the dead horse, but...

$\mathbb{Q} + X \mathbb{R}[X] \subset \mathbb{R}[X]$

is one of many similar examples.