# If R[x] is a UFD, then R is a UFD.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I see the statement that if R is UFD then R[x] is a UFD, but is the converse of the statement, which is that if R[x] is a UFD, then R is a UFD, true?

Comment: Since $R$ can be viewed as a subring of $R[x]$, it seems obvious.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Obvious that it is a subring...  however it is not useful in showing it’s a ufd...

Comment: @rschwieb,why it is not useful in showing that it is ufd?since R is subring of R[X],if we take any element of R then being element of R[X] its factorisation into irreducibles is unique upto order and associates,what remains to show now??????

Comment: @Ibs Sorry, I wasn't clear. As explained in the answers below, a subring of a UFD need not be a UFD. That is what I was chafing at.  *However* in the particular case of showing $R$ is a UFD if $R[x]$ is, we are saved because of how the ring is organized.  For a general subring of a ring, it is not clear that a factorization of something in the subring in terms of elements of the containing ring tells us anything at all. But here the degrees of polynomials help to show that the factorization is relevant after all.

Comment: @Wuestenfux We can see that $\mathbb{C}$ is a field and so a UFD however the subring $\mathbb{Z}[ \sqrt{-5}]$ is not a UFD.

Answer (score 7):

I have written a full proof at the bottom (in case the hint isn't enough).

Hint: Since $R\lbrack x\rbrack$ is a UFD, it is (in particular) an integral domain. Hence degree considerations work -- i.e. we always have equality $\deg (fg)=\deg f+\deg g$, unlike in the general case where 
$\deg (fg) \leq \deg f + \deg g$.

It follows that whenever we factorize elements of $R$ in $R\lbrack x\rbrack$, we actually get (by degree considerations) a factorization in $R$.

Also, elements of $R$ which are irreducible in $R\lbrack x\rbrack$ must in particular be irreducible in $R$. This is a fairly straightforward argument, just remember that the units of $R\lbrack x\rbrack$ are simply the units of $R$ viewed as constant polynomials.

***Addendum.*** In general, **a subring of a UFD need not be a UFD.** As mentioned in an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613913/give-an-example-of-a-ufd-having-a-subring-which-is-not-a-ufd), the easiest counterexamples are constructed by choosing an integral domain which is not a UFD, then noting that this ring is a subring of its field of fractions (which is trivially a UFD). **This is why we need arguments like the one sketched above, which in one way or another use the fact that $R\lbrack x\rbrack$ consists of polynomials over $R$.**

So that you don't have to take my word for it: There are, of course, many examples of non-UFD integral domains. Trotter observed (in an article cited by Lang) that the well-known identity $\cos^2x + \sin^2x = 1$ implies the non-unique irreducible factorizations 
$$\sin^2(x)=(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)$$
 in the ring of trigonometric polynomials $\mathbb R \lbrack \sin x,\cos x\rbrack$. Meanwhile, $\mathbb R \lbrack \sin x,\cos x\rbrack$ is easily seen to be an integral domain.

Here is the promised proof that if $R\lbrack x\rbrack$ is a UFD, then $R$ is a UFD.

***Proof.*** This (simple) proof is divided into three steps. Recall that the units of $R\lbrack x\rbrack$ are precisely the units of $R$. Also note that since $R\lbrack x\rbrack$ is an integral domain and $R\subset R\lbrack x\rbrack$, then $R$ is an integral domain. Therefore, we just need to show existence and uniqueness of irreducible factorizations in $R$.

Step 1) We claim that $p\in R$ is $R$-irreducible (i.e. irreducible as an element of $R$) iff $p$ is $R\lbrack x\rbrack$ irreducible. We may assume $p\neq 0$. The "if" part is trivial. Indeed, if $p = ab$ for $a,b\in R$, then $p = ab$ is also a factorization in $R\lbrack x\rbrack$. Hence wlog $a$ must be a unit in $R\lbrack x\rbrack$, so also a unit in $R$. As for "only if", suppose $p$ is $R$-irreducible and $p = fg$ is a factorization in $R\lbrack x\rbrack$. Then
\begin{align*}
\deg f + \deg g = \deg p = 0  &\Rightarrow \deg f = \deg g = 0 \\
&\Rightarrow f,g\in R.
\end{align*}
Hence $p = fg$ is a factorization in $R$, so wlog $f$ is a unit in $R$, thus also a unit in $R\lbrack x\rbrack$.

Step 2) If $a\in R$, then $a$ has a factorization
\begin{align}\label{factors}
a = p_1\dots p_n \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $p_i$ is an irreducible element of $R\lbrack x\rbrack$ for $i = 1,\dots ,n$. As in step 1,
$$
\deg p_1 + \dots + \deg p_n = \deg a = 0 \Rightarrow p_i \in R\quad i = 1,\dots ,n.
$$
By step 1, each $p_i$ is therefore $R$-irreducible. Then \eqref{factors} is an irreducible factorization in $R$.

Step 3) It remains to show uniqueness. Suppose $a\in R$ and $p_1,\dots ,p_n$ and $q_1,\dots ,q_m$ are irreducible elements in $R$ with
\begin{align}\label{twofactors}
p_1\dots p_n = a = q_1\dots q_m.\tag{2}
\end{align}
By step 1), \eqref{twofactors} gives two $R\lbrack x\rbrack$-irreducible factorizations of $a$. But $R\lbrack x\rbrack$ is a UFD, so $m = n$ and there is a permuation $\sigma \colon \lbrace 1,\dots ,n\rbrace\rightarrow \lbrace 1,\dots ,n\rbrace$ and units $u_i$ ($i=1,\dots ,n$) in $R\lbrack x\rbrack$ so that
\begin{align}\label{perm}
p_i = u_iq_{\sigma (i)}\quad i=1,\dots ,n. \tag{3}
\end{align}
But $u_i$ is also a unit in $R$, so \eqref{perm} shows that $p_1\dots p_n$ and $q_1\dots q_m$ are the same factorization (up to permutation and unit) in $R$. This completes the proof. QED.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose otherwise; i.e. there exist an element of $R$ which has distinct prime factorisations ("really" distinct, they're not reorderings/unit multiplications of each other). Then this element is also an element of $R[x]$. All we need to show is that primes in $R$ remain primes when viewed as an element of $R[x]$, and that non-units remain non-units, in order to contradict that $R[x]$ is a UFD.